# Why this code failed to run

Tags: c++

i want to generate a tree of siblings as under

```
                                   ABCD
                                 /  | \ \
                                A   B  C D
```

ABCD has four nodes i have taken a array for this *next[]. but this code does not run successfully but it produces the sequence. i have written code in main() which provide characters to the enque function. e.g. str.at(x) where x is variable in for loop.

```
     struct node
    {
        string info;
        struct node *next[];
    }*root,*child;

    string str, goal;
    int dept=0,bnod=0,cl,z=0;
    void enqueue(string n);

    void enqueue(string n)
    {

        node *p, *temp;
        p=new node[sizeof(str.length())];
        p->info=n;
        for (int x=0;x<str.length();x++)
        p->next[x]=NULL;
        if(root==NULL)
        {
            root=p;
            child=p;
        }
        else
        {   
            cout<<" cl="<<cl<<endl;
            if(cl<str.length())
            {
                child->next[cl]=p;
            temp=child->next[cl];

            cout<<"chile-info "<<temp->info<<endl;
            }   
            else
                cout<<" clif="<<cl<<endl;
}
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter String: sham
cl=0
chile-info s
cl=1
chile-info h
cl=2
chile-info a
cl=3
chile-info m

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 2s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, where does "RUN FAILED" come from? Is that specific to your compiler?

Secondly, about the line `p=new node[sizeof(str.length())];`, it probably won't give you what you wanted because you're taking the `sizeof` of an unsigned integer ( which, depending on your platform is likely to give you 4 regardless of the string length. Which is not what you're after - you want the actual length of the string ).

So - since you're already using `std::string`, why not use `std::vector`? Your code would look a lot friendlier :-)

If I take the first couple of lines as your desired output ( sorry, the code you posted is very hard to decipher, and I don't think it compiles either, so I'm ignoring it ;-) )

Would something like this work better for you?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef struct node
{
  std::string info;
  std::vector<struct node*> children;
}Node;

Node * enqueue(std::string str)
{
  Node * root;
  root = new Node();

  root->info = str;

  for (int x = 0; x < str.length(); x++)
  {
    Node * temp = new Node();
    temp->info = str[x];
    root->children.push_back(temp);
  }

  return root;
}

int main()
{
  Node * myRoot = enqueue("ABCD");

  std::cout << myRoot->info << "\n";

  for( int i = 0; i < myRoot->children.size(); i++)
  {
    std::cout << myRoot->children[i]->info << ", ";
  }

  char c;
  std::cin >> c;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `const std::string &` as the parameter type instead of `std::string`, to make the code look great. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems not full.
At least the line

```
p=new node[sizeof(str.length())];
```

seems wrong.
I guess enqueue should be something similar to the following:

```
 struct node
    {
        string info;
        struct node *next; // [] - is not necessary here
    }*root,*child;

    string str, goal;
    int dept=0,bnod=0,cl,z=0;
void enqueue(string n)
{

node *p, *temp;
p = new node;
p->next = new node[str.length()];
p->info=n;
for (int x=0;x<str.length();x++)
{
    p->next[x] = new node;
    p->next[x]->next = 0;
    p->next[x]->info = str[x];
}

if(root==NULL)
{
    root=p;
    child=p;
}
}
```

Please provide more info to give a more correct answer

Comment: p->next = new node[str.length()]; yes but this give error incompatible types in assignment of ‘node*’ to ‘node* [0]’

Comment: your code is working but when i enter string of length 5 it gives the same error otherwise it works fine

Comment: Please provide the code that calls 'enqueue' to see what is wrong